# Possible to insert class based on language?

Tags: theming

Is it possible to insert additional class to the body tag through the page.tpl.php file but with the condition:

```
$language->language == 'zh-hans'
```

in an IF statement?

I tried adding the following code to the template.php:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
global $language;
if ($language->language == 'zh-hans') {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = "zh-hans";
}
```

}

but I'm not sure if the function is supposed to be used like this. The class does not appear.

Comment: Why would you need that? If you have [i18n](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) installed and enabled, you should already have classes like `i18n-en` on your `<body>`

Comment: But of course yes, it is possible. Post the code you tried and how it failed, if you want us to tell what was wrong.

Comment: edited question.

Comment: @HuiJingChen You're new to PHP I take it? You'll need to learn a bit more about the language before you can write Drupal code. As a starting point, ask yourself where `$language` is being defined in your code (it happens to be a global variable, so Google that). Even after the edit this is still a duplicate of the other question; using a slightly different conditional isn't enough to warrant a new question asking essentially the same thing

Comment: noted. i apologise for the duplicate.

Comment: Not a problem, looks like your issue has evolved anyway so I'll open this back up